# Model help using Scikit-learn when using GridSearch

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cross-validation, grid-search

As part of the Enron project, built the attached model, Below is the summary of the steps,

#### Below model gives highly perfect scores

```
cv = StratifiedShuffleSplit(n_splits = 100, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 42)
gcv = GridSearchCV(pipe, clf_params,cv=cv)

gcv.fit(features,labels) ---> with the full dataset

for train_ind, test_ind in cv.split(features,labels):
    x_train, x_test = features[train_ind], features[test_ind]
    y_train, y_test = labels[train_ind],labels[test_ind]

    gcv.best_estimator_.predict(x_test)
```

#### Below model gives more reasonable but low scores

```
cv = StratifiedShuffleSplit(n_splits = 100, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 42)
gcv = GridSearchCV(pipe, clf_params,cv=cv)

gcv.fit(features,labels) ---> with the full dataset

for train_ind, test_ind in cv.split(features,labels):
     x_train, x_test = features[train_ind], features[test_ind]
     y_train, y_test = labels[train_ind],labels[test_ind]

     gcv.best_estimator_.fit(x_train,y_train)
     gcv.best_estimator_.predict(x_test)
```

1. Used Kbest to find out the scores and sorted the features and trying a combination of higher and lower scores.
2. Used SVM with a GridSearch using a StratifiedShuffle
3. Used the best_estimator_  to predict and calculate the precision and recall.

The problem is estimator is spitting out perfect scores, in some case 1

But when I refit the best classifier on training data then run the test it gives reasonable scores.

My doubt/question was what exactly GridSearch does with the test data after the split using the Shuffle split object we send in to it. I assumed it would not fit anything on Test data, if that was true then when I predict using the same test data, it should not give this high scores right.? since i used random_state value, the shufflesplit should have created the same copy for the Grid fit and also for the predict.

So, is using the same Shufflesplit for two wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically the grid search will:

- Try every combination of your parameter grid
- For each of them it will do a K-fold cross validation
- Select the best available.

So your second case is the good one. Otherwise you are actually predicting data that you trained with (which is not the case in the second option, there you only keep the best parameters from your gridsearch)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. It makes sense now. I thought the grid search actually just run tests on the test data and not use that for training at all. Really appreciate the response.

Answer (score 14):

[GridSearchCV](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html) as @Gauthier Feuillen said is used to search best parameters of an estimator for given data.
Description of GridSearchCV:-

1. `gcv = GridSearchCV(pipe, clf_params,cv=cv)`
2. `gcv.fit(features,labels)`
3. `clf_params` will be expanded to get all possible combinations separate using [ParameterGrid](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.ParameterGrid.html).
4. `features` will now be split into `features_train` and `features_test` using `cv`. Same for `labels`
5. Now the gridSearch estimator (pipe) will be trained using `features_train` and `labels_inner` and scored using `features_test` and `labels_test`.
6. **For each possible combination of parameters** in step 3, The **steps 4 and 5 will be repeated** for `cv_iterations`. The average of score across cv iterations will be calculated, which will be assigned to that parameter combination. This can be accessed using `cv_results_` attribute of gridSearch.
7. For the parameters which give the best score, the internal estimator will be **re initialized using those parameters and refit for the whole data** supplied into it(features and labels).

**Because of last step, you are getting different scores in first and second approach**. Because in the first approach, all data is used for training and you are predicting for that data only. Second approach has prediction on previously unseen data.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. Really appreciate it.  just two small things, 

I think you meant steps 4 & 5 will be repeated in step 6.

Step 7 is done only when refit = True in GridSearch object right.?

Comment: Yes, step 7 is performed when `refit=True`. By default `refit=True` in GridSearchCV(). And you also in your code havent specified `refit` parameter, thats why I did not use it.

Comment: It's a great and very detailed answer!

Comment: @VivekKumar +1 for nice explanation. In the second approach, he has fit training data once again to the final model _(found by best_estimator_)_ . Is this step needed?

Comment: @Md.SabbirAhmed  Initially with `refit` param in `GridSearchCV` the `best_estimator_` will be trained on whole data supplied in `GridSearchCV.fit()`. For cross-validation that is not what we want. So in his second approach, he is just calculating the performance of best found parameters in cross-validation folds by training the `best_estimator_` again on train data of each fold. That is correct but is not needed because `GridSearchCV`  will calculate the scores for each fold on each param combination.

Comment: @VivekKumar Thanks once again. I understood it.