# Interpreting sklearns' GridSearchCV best score

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation, grid-search

I would like to know the difference between the score returned by `GridSearchCV` and the `R2` metric calculated as below. In other cases I receive the grid search score highly negative (same applies for `cross_val_score`) and I would be grateful for explaining what it is.

```
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.model_selection import (cross_val_score, GridSearchCV)
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, r2_score
from sklearn import tree

diabetes = datasets.load_diabetes()
X = diabetes.data[:150]
y = diabetes.target[:150]
X = pd.DataFrame(X)

parameters = {'splitter':('best','random'), 
              'max_depth':np.arange(1,10), 
              'min_samples_split':np.arange(2,10), 
              'min_samples_leaf':np.arange(1,5)}

regressor = GridSearchCV(DecisionTreeRegressor(), parameters, scoring = 'r2', cv = 5)
regressor.fit(X, y)

print('Best score: ', regressor.best_score_)
best = regressor.best_estimator_
print('R2: ', r2_score(y_pred = best.predict(X), y_true = y))
```

Comment: This might be relevant: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/12900/when-is-r-squared-negative

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/12900/when-is-r-squared-negative) linked by @Davide in the comments has answers why you get a positive `R2` score - your model performs better than a constant prediction. At the same time you can get negative values in other situation, if your models there perform bad.

the reason for the difference in values is that `regressor.best_score_` is evaluated on a particular fold out of the 5-fold split that you do, whereas `r2_score(y_pred = best.predict(X), y_true = y)` evaluates the same model (`regressor.best_estimator_`) but on the full sample (including the (5-1)-fold sub-set that was used to train that estimator)

Answer (score 10):

The `regressor.best_score_` is the average of r2 scores on left-out test folds for the best parameter combination.

In your example, the cv=5, so the data will be split into train and test folds 5 times. The model will be fitted on train and scored on test. These 5 test scores are averaged to get the score.   Please see [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html):

> "best_score_: Mean cross-validated score of the best_estimator"

The above process repeats for all parameter combinations. And the best average score from it is assigned to the `best_score_`.

You can look [at my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42364900/3374996) for complete working of GridSearchCV

After finding the best parameters, the model is trained on full data.

`r2_score(y_pred = best.predict(X), y_true = y)`

is on the same data as the model is trained on, so in most cases, it will be higher.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this is incorrect. Compare: regressor.best_score_ to regressor.cv_results_. I just did this and it is clear that best_score_ is set equal to the LARGEST mean_test_score value; NOT the average of them, which is unfortunate. I am using sklearn 0.20.3

Comment: @NLR And what does `mean_test_score` sounds like? Emphasis on `mean`. I never said that it is an average of all `mean_test_score` values. I said its an average of values from all test folds.

Comment: regressor.best_score_ outputs the SINGLE best value from the folds. It returns the score for one fold. I found this out by looking at the output of the cross validation using regressor.cv_results_. If you take the mean of the test scores (mean_test_score), it is different from the best_score_. Try it yourself and you'll see what I mean. (There is a small typo in my first comment: it should read "...set equal to the LARGEST test_score"; not "mean_test_score". I manually calculated the mean.)