# How is Cross Validation performed and how GridSearchCV() specifically?

Tags: python, keras, neural-network, cross-validation

How is [GridSearchCV()](http://scikit-learn.sourceforge.net/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.grid_search.GridSearchCV.html) (and or [RandomizedSearchCV()](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.RandomizedSearchCV.html)) implemented in scikit? I wonder about the following: When using one of these techniques, how are the following aspects taken into account:

- validation set
- model selection
- hyperparameter tuning
- prediction

? Here is a picture that summarizes my confusion:

[image: CV]

What happens when and how often? Maybe to keep it simple, let's assume a single neural network acting as our model. 
My understanding so far:

In the first iteration, the model is fit on the training fold, separated into different folds. Here I struggle already: Is the model trained on a single fold and then tested on the validation fold? 
What happens then with the next fold? Does the model keep the weights achieved by its first training fold or will it re-initialize for the next training fold?

To be more precise: In the first iteration, is the model fit four times and tested four times on the validation set, independently between all folds?

When the next iteration begins, the model keeps no information from the first iteration, right?
Thus, are all iterations and all folds are independent from each other? 
How are the hyperparameters tuned here?

In above example, there are 25 folds in total. Is the model with a constant set of hyperparameters fit and tested 20 times?
Let's say, we have two hyperparameters to tune: Learning rate and dropout rate, both with two levels:

- learning_rate = [0.3, 0.6] and
- dropout_rate = [0.4, 0.8].

Will the neural net now fitted 80 times? And when having not only a single model but e.g. two models (neural network and random forest), the whole procedure will be performed twice?

Is there a possibility to see how many folds `GridSearchCV()` will consider?

I have seen [Does GridSearchCV perform cross-validation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49160206/does-gridsearchcv-perform-cross-validation) , [Model help using Scikit-learn when using GridSearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42362027/model-help-using-scikit-learn-when-using-gridsearch/42364900#42364900) and [scikit-learn GridSearchCV with multiple repetitions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42228735/scikit-learn-gridsearchcv-with-multiple-repetitions/42230764#42230764) but I can't see a clear and precise answer to my questions.

Comment: Yes, your NN will be fitted 80 times, and yes it will be x2 if you test on another model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the k-folds method:

you split your training set into n parts (k folds) for example 5. You take de first part as the validation set and the 4 other parts as the training set. You train and this gives you a training/CV performance. You do this 5 (number of folds) times, each folds become the validation set and the others de training set. At the end you do the mean of the performances to obtain the cv performance of your model. This is for the k-fold.

Now, GridSearchCV is an hyperparameter tuner which uses k-folds method. The principel is you give to gridsearch a dictionary with all the hyper parameters you want to test then it will tests all the hyperparameters (dictionary) and select the best set of hyperparameters (those with the best model cv performance). It can take a very loooooooong time.

You pass a model (estimator) in gridsearch, a set of params and if you want the number of k-folds.

Example:

```
GridSearchCV(SVC(), parameters, cv = 5)
```

where `SVC()` is the estimator, parameters is your dictionary of hyperparameters and cv is the number of folds.

Comment: Thanks, but I still don't know about how it is performed specifically. Is the model fit once or four times in the first iteration? And what will change in the 2nd iteration beside the folds?

Comment: in the first iteration it will be fitted once, then the valid fold change and the model fit once, then the valid fold change and so on

Comment: Then I would make all the images differently.. thanks! And will the hyperparameters change from one iteration to the other?

Comment: Each time an hyperparameter change, the model is tested k times. The k-folds method is done after an hyperparameter change. It is the fitting process. The algo defines an hyperparameter set and then fit it k times.

Comment: Thank you! To finalize: Given two parameters with two levels (like above) and k=5-fold. This will result in 20 fits, right?

Comment: Ok, thank you! Like described, there were so many possibilities how to see/understand/implement CV and I needed some response to narrow them down..  and yes, I'm performing gridsearchcv() with cpu only actually and it takes hours or rather days..